# POST method doesn't work in Yii2 using PHP

Tags: php, html, yii2

My application is using Yii2. I had insert this code into one of the page:

```
Multiple Selection: <input name="multi" type="checkbox" value="selected" />&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

I want to know whether this `checkbox` is been selected a not. Any idea how can i do it? 
I had tried this method but it doesn't work:

```
if($_POST['multi'] == 'selected')
{ //do sth
}
```

Comment: have you added form method i.e. method="POST"?

Comment: Yes, I do @Revolution

Answer (score 1):

If the checkbox has been checked, it will be sent in the `POST`. Otherwise, it will be not. So:

```
if (isset($_POST['multi'])) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: No matter if i have select the checkbox, it i will still pass through using your  method

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayHelper

```
$multi = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getValue($_POST ,'multi' , null);
if($multi === 'selected'){
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (isset($_POST['multi']) && 'selected' == $_POST['multi']) {
    //do stuff
}
```